# two while loop fetching data from two queries only show one result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this code that I use to fetch data from a database:

```
function show_volanti($data){

    $con = $data;       // PASSO CONNESSIONE
    $id = 1;            // 1 VOLANTE
    $visibile = 1;      // VARIABILE DI VISIBILITA'

    $rows1 = array();   // PREPARO ARRAY 1 PER ID ARTICOLI VOLANTE
    $rows2 = array();   // PREPARO ARRAY 2 PER LE FOTO VOLANTI

    $id_articoli = '';  // RIFERIMENTO ARTICOLI PER SECONDA QUERY GALLERIA
    $g = '';            // RIFERIMENTO ASSOCIAZIONE GALLERY VIEWER
    //$rif_id = '';     // RIF_ID SE OK DA CANCELLARE


    $query1 = "SELECT articoli.id AS id_articoli,
                                      articoli.titolo,
                                      articoli.descrizione
                                      FROM articoli
                                      WHERE articoli.genere1 = ?
                                      AND articoli.visibile = ?";

    $query2 = "SELECT galleria.id AS id_galleria,
                                    galleria.foto,
                                    galleria.rif_id
                                    FROM galleria
                                    WHERE galleria.rif_id = ?";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);     // INIZIALIZZO LA CONNESSIONE

    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$query1);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'ii',$id,$visibile);   // LEGO I PARAMETRI

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);     // ESEGUO LA QUERY

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,
                            $rows1['id_articoli'],
                            $rows1['titolo'],
                            $rows1['descrizione']);     // CREO RIFERIMENTO PER GALLERIA NEL VIEWER

    $html = "";
    $html .= "<div class='container'>";

    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){

        $id_articoli = $rows1['id_articoli'];


        $html .= "  <div class='row'>";
        $html .= "    <div class='col-sm-12'>";
        $html .= "      <div class='panel panel-default'>";
        $html .= "        <div class='panel-body'>";


        $html .= "            <div class='col'>";
        $html .= "              <div class='panel panel-default'>";
        $html .= "                <div class='panel-heading'><b>$rows1[titolo]</b></div>";
        $html .= "                  <div class='panel-body'>";
        $html .= "                      <div class='row'>";
        $html .= "                          <div class='class_p'>$rows1[descrizione]</div>";
        $html .= "                      <div> <!-- end first row -->";

        $html .= "                      <div class='class_container clearfix'>";


        mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$query2);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'i',$id_articoli);     // LEGO I PARAMETRI

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);     // ESEGUO LA QUERY

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,
                                $rows2['id_galleria'],
                                $rows2['foto'],
                                $rows2['rif_id']);                                  

        while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){

            $g = '';
            $g .= "g";
            $g .= $rows2['rif_id'];

            $html .= "<div class='thumbnail col-sm-2'>";
            $html .= "<div class='class_img'>";
            $html .= "<a href='$rows2[foto]' data-toggle='lightbox' data-gallery='$g' >";
            $html .= "<img src='$rows2[foto]' class='img-fluid'>";
            $html .= "</a>";
            $html .= "</div> <!-- end class_img -->";
            $html .= "</div> <!-- end thumbnail col-sm-2- -->"; 
        }

        $html .= "</div> <!-- end class_container -->";

        $html .= "</div> <!-- end panel body -->";
        $html .= "</div> <!-- end panel panel-default -->";
        $html .= "</div> <!-- end col -->";
        $html .= "</div> <!-- end panel-body -->";
        $html .= "</div> <!-- end panel panel-default -->";
        $html .= "</div> <!-- end col-sm-12 -->";
        $html .= "</div> <!-- end row -->";
    }

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);   // CHIUDO LO STATEMENT
    mysqli_close($con);         // CHIUDO CONNESSIONE   
    return $html;
}
```

The code partially works because it show the result but it only show one result and inside the database i have more results to show so it doesn't work as it should.. May you help me to find the error?

Comment: Hint:  You want a single query with `JOIN`.

Comment: initially i wrote a single query with a left join but then I stopped because the "problem" is that i do not know how many articles there are in the database and I don't know how many photos there are per article and I don't know how to do a double while loop knowing that I cannot know how many photos per article i have inside the database.. sorry for my english hope you understand

Comment: that was my first query with left join:

"SELECT articoli.id, articoli.titolo, articoli.descrizione, galleria.id, galleria.foto, galleria.rif_id FROM articoli LEFT JOIN galleria ON articoli.id = galleria.rif_id WHERE articoli.genere1 = 1 AND articoli.visibile = 1;"

Comment: . . I  might suggest that you ask *another* question.  Show sample data, desired results, and leave out the PHP code.  You might find that you can do all the work in the database.

Comment: ok so I can close this question a repost with another title? or change the title and the tags?

Comment: by the way I do not know if my php code (the two while loops) is correct..

Comment: Your PHP is not correct. You use `$stmt` multiple times and overwrite it in your `while` loop. You don't need to query in the loop though, as @GordonLinoff has pointed out. If you use a `join` you can do this with 1 query, then just loop that result.

Comment: ok thanks i accept the answer and do another one. So i accept the answer of Gordon Linoff and open a new question with the query for database. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're reusing the same variables for both external and internal loop. For example, you're using $stmt for both of them. I'm not sure if that's why you're getting only one result (as it may depend on the amount of results you received from each of them), but I would look into that.

As a debug tip, I would remove all code relevant to the external loop and first print out the results of the external ones properly. Once you have that working, start adding the internal loop code and make sure it works. Do not reuse the same variables though.